# How to convert time.Time variable to atomic in Go?

Tags: go, atomic

In my RESTFUL web service which is an online game, I'm storing starting time of every question in an global variable like this: `var MyTime time.Time` which I should update it after every level of the game. My application is distributed, so I want to make sure all of my apps are not updating it at the same time. That's why I've decided to make it atomic.
Actually I'm familiar with Golang `sync/atomic` package.
I tried to use `atomic.LoadPointer()` method but it needs specific argument type which isn't safe. Do you any other way for this?

**Update:** 
Okay I solved my problem like this. 
I defined time variable as `atomic.Value` and used atomic Load and Store methods. This is the code: 
`var myTime atomic.Value
 myTime.Store(newTime)` and load `myTime.Load().(time.Time)`.

Consider that Load() method returns interface, so you should write (time.Time) at the end in order to convert it to time.Time type.

Answer (score 5):

This can't be done, as such, because [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=5813:6814#L106) is a compound type:

```
type Time struct {
    // wall and ext encode the wall time seconds, wall time nanoseconds,
    // and optional monotonic clock reading in nanoseconds.
    //
    // From high to low bit position, wall encodes a 1-bit flag (hasMonotonic),
    // a 33-bit seconds field, and a 30-bit wall time nanoseconds field.
    // The nanoseconds field is in the range [0, 999999999].
    // If the hasMonotonic bit is 0, then the 33-bit field must be zero
    // and the full signed 64-bit wall seconds since Jan 1 year 1 is stored in ext.
    // If the hasMonotonic bit is 1, then the 33-bit field holds a 33-bit
    // unsigned wall seconds since Jan 1 year 1885, and ext holds a
    // signed 64-bit monotonic clock reading, nanoseconds since process start.
    wall uint64
    ext  int64

    // loc specifies the Location that should be used to
    // determine the minute, hour, month, day, and year
    // that correspond to this Time.
    // The nil location means UTC.
    // All UTC times are represented with loc==nil, never loc==&utcLoc.
    loc *Location
}
```

However, you can do this with pointers, so `*time.Time` would be possible, if this suits your needs. But of course, this is discouraged, by virtue of the fact that `atomic.LoadPointer` and `atomic.StorePointer` use the `unsafe` package to accomplish their magic.

A much better approach, if it will work for you, is just to use a mutex to protect your value. There are many ways to do this, but one minimal example:

```
type MyTime struct {
    t  time.Time
    mu sync.RWMutex
}

func (t *MyTime) Time() time.Time {
    t.mu.RLock()
    defer t.mu.RUnlock()
    return t.t
}

func (t *MyTime) SetTime(tm time.Time) {
    t.mu.Lock()
    defer t.mu.Unlock()
    t.t = tm
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can keep unix time https://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_Time_Unix as atomic which is int64. Then convert to go time after you've read atomic value.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in the timestamp, you could simply keep a reference to the unix time, which is `int64` and atomically update that.

```
var ts int64

func main() {
    atomic.StoreInt64(&ts, time.Now().Unix())
    t := time.Unix(atomic.LoadInt64(&ts), 0)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Instead, if you need the entire `Time` struct, read on.

#### Go 1.19 and above

If you are okay with storing a pointer to a `time.Time` object, you can use [`atomic.Pointer`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic@master#Pointer), which is a generic struct that abstracts `atomic.LoadPointer` and `atomic.StorePointer`. As a simple example:

```
// instantiate generic struct with time.Time
var at = atomic.Pointer[time.Time]{}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()

    at.Store(&t)
    t = *at.Load()

    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/KwTMgvJIenx?v=gotip

Note that in Go 1.19 you can also use [`atomic.Int64`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic@master#Int64). The advantage of these atomic types instead of top-level functions is that it's more fool-proof; it's impossible to access the value non-atomically as it's hidden behind the struct.